# Problem with "Route" resource in laravel 8

Tags: laravel

My app was working fine until I wanted to replace my "get" routes with a single "resource" to be able to include a delete function. I remind you that I am a beginner in laravel so it is surely due to the fact that I can not be able to make a "resource" route.
This is my code :

```
Route::get('/', function(){
    return view('front.pages.homepage');
})->name('homepage');

Route::get('/garages', [GarageController::class, 'index'])->name('garage.index');
Route::get('/garages/{garage}', [GarageController::class, 'show'])->name('garage.show');
Route::get('/garages_create', [GarageController::class, 'create'])->name('garage.create');
Route::post('/garages_create', [GarageController::class, 'garage_create'])->name('garage_create');

Route::resource('cars', [CarController::class]);
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Car;
use App\Models\Garage;

class CarController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $list = Car::paginate(10);

        return view('cars', [
            'list' => $list
        ]);
    }


    public function store()
    {
        $garages = Garage::orderBy('name')->get();
        return view('carCreate/carCreate', [
            'garages' => $garages,
        ]);
    }
    


    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        {
            $request->validate([
                'name' => 'required',
                'release_year' => 'required',
                'garage_id' => 'required', 'exists:garage_id'
            ]);
            
            $car = new Car();
            $car->name = $request->name;
            $car->release_year = $request->release_year;
            $car->garage_id = $request->garage_id;
            $car->save();
            return redirect('/cars');
        }
    }

    public function show(Car $car)
    {
        return view('carShow/carShow', compact('car'));
    }


    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }


    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

And my error is : ErrorException
Array to string conversion

Comment: You dont need to specify your resource controller in square brackets. Replace it with the following code.

`Route::resource('cars', CarController::class);`

And make sure to import it with correct namespace.

Comment: Ok that was it thank you !